# Why is there extra space below my scroll view?

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I have a scroll view that I would like to fill the whole screen, I have the base `LinearLayout`, then inside that a `ScrollView`, and then inside that a single `LinearLayout` containing several textfields and labels. I am running in API level 8. What I wind up with on the emulator is this:

[image: The bottom of my emulator]

So the `ScrollView` should go all the way to the bottom, but I can't figure out what is causing it not to take up all the space on the screen? Does anybody have any suggestions?

Below is my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <TextView 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:id="@+id/textView1" 
                android:text="@string/create_account_header" 
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textStyle="bold">
            </TextView>
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView2" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/enter_email"></TextView>
            <EditText android:inputType="textEmailAddress" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/emailAddress"></EditText>
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView3" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Email Address Again:"></TextView>
            <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:inputType="textEmailAddress" android:id="@+id/emailAddressConfirmation">
                <requestFocus></requestFocus>
            </EditText>
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView6" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Username:"></TextView>
            <EditText android:inputType="textPersonName" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_width="match_parent"></EditText>
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView4" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Password:"></TextView>
            <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:inputType="textPassword" android:id="@+id/password"></EditText>
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView5" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Confirm Password:"></TextView>
            <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:inputType="textPassword" android:id="@+id/passwordConfirmation"></EditText>
            <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/generic_image" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageButton1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageButton>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your layout code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so I had the emulator set to scale to 75% size, when I turned this off, the problem disappeared... So I think it was probably an emulator issue.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to take ScrollView inside the LinearLayout, remove it and make ScrollView as parent container.

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <TextView 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:id="@+id/textView1" 
                android:text="@string/create_account_header" 
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textStyle="bold">
            </TextView>
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView2" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/enter_email"></TextView>
            <EditText android:inputType="textEmailAddress" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/emailAddress"></EditText>
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView3" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Email Address Again:"></TextView>
            <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:inputType="textEmailAddress" android:id="@+id/emailAddressConfirmation">
                <requestFocus></requestFocus>
            </EditText>
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView6" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Username:"></TextView>
            <EditText android:inputType="textPersonName" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_width="match_parent"></EditText>
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView4" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Password:"></TextView>
            <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:inputType="textPassword" android:id="@+id/password"></EditText>
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView5" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Confirm Password:"></TextView>
            <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:inputType="textPassword" android:id="@+id/passwordConfirmation"></EditText>
            <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/generic_image" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageButton1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageButton>
        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I changed it to that, but I am still having the same problem. Could It be an emulator problem?

Comment: provide "fill_parent" to scrollview and try.

Comment: I had tried various combinations of fill_parent vs match_parent before I posted, but I think it was actually something with the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your match_parent into wrap_content or fill_parent.It might solve your problem.